# How to 301 redirect domain.com to domain.com/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What is the htaccess code to 301 redirect my homepage from www.domain.com to www.domain.com/ and domain.com should also go to www.domain.com/

the non-www to www works fine, all internal redirects work, e.g. www.domain.com/abc/index.php goes to www.domain.com/abc/

However I also want that the homepage itself goes from .com to .com/

Please advise.

Comment: Where is your current code? How can we help you adjust it to fix that if you haven't provided it?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such URL as `http://www.domain.com`. This is how we write it in the browser (or just `www.domain.com`) but in the background, the browser connects to `www.domain.com` and asks for `/` no matter if it is present in the URL or not.

In other words, `http://www.domain.com` is, in fact, a shorter way to write `http://www.domain.com/`.

There is no point in rewriting or redirecting `www.domain.com` to `www.domain.com/`. The most you can get if you try to do it is an infinite loop.